# Binding an item inside DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf

In my xaml file, I have:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Configuration:Drivers}">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Cars}" FontWeight="Normal" />   
<DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Configuration:Car}">
    <UniformGrid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5,1,5,2" Columns="2">                                              
         <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Enabled, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>    
         <CheckBox Visibility="{Binding SaveImage, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    </UniformGrid>      
</DataTemplate>
```

For each car, it has: Enabled property but does not have SaveImage property.

```
Car
{
   public bool Enabled {}
}
```

The 'SaveImage' is set in globally. I don't know how to bind that: bool SaveImage inside the DataTemplate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DataTemplates` are an encapsulation boundary, so you cannot allways use `FindAncestor` to get the desired data. A good solution is to put your `ViewModel` in your XAML as a `StaticResource` and then set the `DataContext` of you `LayoutRoot` grid to this `StaticResource`, then all other DataTemplates can access the `DataContext` via the same `StaticResource`

**EXAMPLE**

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:MyViewModel x:Key="viewmodel" />
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Configuration:Car}">
        <UniformGrid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5,1,5,2" Columns="2">
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Enabled, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            <CheckBox Visibility="{Binding Source={StaticResource viewmodel}, 
                Path=SaveImage, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        </UniformGrid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource viewmodel}}">

</Grid>
```

Comment: could you please give an example?

Comment: I am almost there. Thanks a lot. However, when the property: SaveImage in MyViewModel is changed to Visibility.Visible from default of: Hidden, the Visibility of the CheckBox does not change. I even set: Mode=TwoWay in the Binding. Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: Make sure your viewmodel implements INotifyPropertyChanged, and is firing the correct notifications

Comment: thanks. I was very quickly in my previous comment. If I make it: <local:MyViewModel x:Key="viewmodel" /> with go with a default constructor: MyViewModel(). it wont be fine because I have a constructor: MyViewModel(Object object) in xaml.cs. Therefore, there are two instances. Hum, it is getting complicated.

Answer (score 0):

If `SaveImage` is available in the `DataContext` of the `ItemsControl` you can bind to it this way:

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding DataContext.SaveImage, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
```

Comment: Thank. but I got this problem: System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'SaveImage' property not found on 'object' ''Drivers' (HashCode=31049803)'. BindingExpression:Path=DataContext.SaveImage; DataItem='ItemsControl' (Name=''); target element is 'CheckBox' (Name=''); target property is 'Visibility' (type 'Visibility')

Comment: I have updated my question. How can I get the parent of the DataContext. I mean one level upper of the Drivers then I can get the 'SaveImage' property

Comment: You need to get to the UserControl whose DataContext is the parent of Drivers. This would be the one you would use as AncestorType.

Comment: I have changed it to be: <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding DataContext.SaveImage, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"/> in my MainWindow.xml.cs,

Comment: I already made it: DataContext = DriversViewModel. In the DriversViewModel there is a property: SaveImage. But I still got the same error: System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.UserControl', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=DataContext.SaveImage; DataItem=null; target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Visibility' (type 'Visibility')

Comment: The reason for you latest error could be that SaveImage is not a Visibility type.

Comment: It is: public Visibility SaveImage {get; set;} Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:
You can try RelativeSource to Bind IsCheck to the abcestor object.

```
{Binding Path=SaveImage, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type typeOfAncestor}}}
```

Solution 2:
Add a property SaveImage to view-model class Car and ref to model SaveImage.It's not a good solution.

Comment: so I need to create a new class of: typeOfAncestor? I dont really understand about this. For the solution 2 is easy to get solved the problem but for the constraint of the design, we can not introduce it for each Car.

Comment: for solution 1, I got this: System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='Config.MultipleCheck', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=SaveImage; DataItem=null; target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Visibility' (type 'Visibility')

Comment: public class MultipleCheck
    {
        Visibility _SaveImage= Visibility.Hidden;

        public Visibility SaveImage
        {
            get { return _SaveImage; }
            set { _SaveImage= value; }
        }
    }